# Name for setup and reversal style of writing?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

What is the name of an expression where two noun/verb sentences are reversed in the second half of the expression?

Here's an example:

> People were created to be loved.
>   Things were created to be used.
>   The reason the world is in chaos is because
>   things are being loved and
>   people are being used.

Comment: Irony.........?

Comment: Chiasmus perhaps?

Comment: note that there is no connection, at all, to "meaning reversal" here.  everything means exactly the same thing throughout.

Comment: @JoeBlow That's not the Q. though.

Comment: I edited the title, which (I believe) was completely wrong.

Comment: curiousdannii has the right term. Though if it extends to 'We worship our work, work at our play, and play at our worship' [Leland Ryken – 'Redeeming the Time: A Christian Approach to Work & Leisure'] I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be an example of [chiasmus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasmus)

Comment: curiousdannii seems to agree.

Comment: May I respectfully disagree based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasmus and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiastic_structure?  It seems to deal with syntactic ordering rather than a swap of meanings.  Please do correct me if my understanding is incorrect.  Thanks.